# Script to create folder with same name as start of filename and move files with same start name into folder

Tags: terminal

Im working on the terminal and have a list of files containing sample data with each sample having a number eg (RNA013477) and each sample having 2 associated files (R1 and R2).[Examples of the files in my folder][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdXSY.png

In order to further process these files I need a subfolder for each file eg folder called RNA013477 and in that folder the 2 files (R1 and R2) attached to that folder.

It is quite time consuming to make a directory with mkdir and then individually move all the files to the correct folder.

Is there a way to do all this in one command line?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you know - superuser really isn't a code writing service...

What you're asking for, is a real "beginner project" in e.g. Python.

The names seem to have a  "base" and then a 5 digit number, just create a simple loop that creates each name in a string, and prints them, one on each line - as first attempt.

Then as you have this, you really should not have any problem using those strings, one at a time, to create folders and move files.

If not by any other means, so then by:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command

Have a go!

Comment: My apologies, im not familiar with the platform. :) but I found a similar question on here and based on that and some additional google search I eventually come to this which seems to work! for file in *; do
  if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    mkdir "${file:0:9}"
    mv "$file" "${file:0:9}"
  fi
done

Comment: Well, that seems to be a beginning at least; that is bash scripting, the Bash guides at www.tldp.org will have more info that you need, good luck.